# Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Не пинайте сильно, пример:

```
$a = '1';
$a[$a] = '2';
echo $a; //12
```

Поясните, что происходит, почему

```
$a = 'one'; $a[$a] = 'two'; echo $a // Warning: Illegal string offset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в первом случае `$a` интерпретируется как строка, индекс `'1'` (начальное значение `$a`) - как число, и запись `$a[$a] = '2'` "раскрывается" в "записать вторым символом (индекс 1) в строку `$a` символ `'2'`". То есть `'1'` превращается в `'12'`.

Во втором случае `'two'` не может быть интерпретирован как индекс символа в строке, вот и выводится сообщение об этом.

Comment: спасибо Эрик ))))